# After I fix my closed question, how or where do I ask for it to be reopened?

Tags: support

I have a question about my English Language & Usage Stack Exchange post: [defining “Well,” when it introduces these sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601711/defining-well-when-it-introduces-these-sentences)

My posted question was closed by a moderator who wrote this instruction for it: “Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.”

Then I edited my posted question accordingly and posted the edited version.

In order to get my question reopened, do I need to notify Stack Exchange of the existence of my edited version or will a moderator routinely see it and decide whether to reopen it?

The original version of my posted question had three parts (three questions on the same topic). In the edited version that I posted, I deleted two of those questions. I intend to re-post those two questions, each one in a separate posting. Is that OK?

Comment: Did you look in [this site's help section](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) before asking here?

Comment: Yes, I did.  And then I sent to Meta the “Support” question that prompted your question because I wanted to find out whether there is something that I should know that would apply specifically to my situation (more specifically than what the Help Section says). Then I received a very relevant explanation from a moderator, Andrew  Leach.

Answer (score 8):

When you edit a closed question, it gets put into a review queue where it can be assessed for re-opening. That's automatic. Your edit also bumps the question in the site's front page, so it appears at the top and is likely to attract attention. That's automatic.

A manual action you can do is flag your question for moderator attention. I would recommend you **don't** do this or don't do it very often, at least until you have a good flagging record. You're raising a flag on one of your own posts. That flag could be deemed helpful [which is a black mark on one of your posts] or unhelpful [which is a black mark against you for raising an unhelpful flag].

In the case you cite, you don't need a list of 77 examples. Three is sufficient! And you have shown no research at all: you could look up *Well* in a reputable dictionary like [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well) and you will find "Exclamation: used to introduce something you are going to say, often to show surprise, doubt, slight disagreement, or anger, or to continue a story," which appears to answer the question. I wouldn't vote to reopen this question.

Yes, posting the other parts of the original question is OK in principle, but make your questions concise and precise, and well-researched. There's lots of help on asking good questions. [Start here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and look at the other topics in the Help sidebar too.